# Unable to sort Solr Geospatial search results

Tags: solr, lucene, gis, geospatial, solarium

How can we have Solr 3.6.1 return the Geospatial search results **both** filtered by `bbox` and sorted by distance?

I tried appending a `&sort=geodist() asc` to the URL as stated in the [Solr docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch), but I get the error:

`sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: geodist()`

**Query URL with sort & bbox (NOT Working)**

```
http://localhost8080/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true
&q=*:*
&fl=id,latlng
&fq={!bbox%20pt=42.352455,-71.048069%20sfield=latlng%20d=5}
&sort=geodist() asc
```

**Query URL with sort (Works)**

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true
&fl=id,latlng
&q=*:*
&sfield=latlng
&pt=42.352455,-71.048069
&sort=geodist()%20asc
```

**Query URL with bbox (Works)**

```
http://localhost8080/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true
&q=*:*
&fl=id,latlng
&fq={!bbox%20pt=42.352455,-71.048069%20sfield=latlng%20d=5}
```

How can I have both `bbox` filtering and sort the results by distance (`geodist()`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply pull out the 'pt' and 'sfield' local-params you have into top-level query parameters, just as you did with the working sort query.  Your fq will be just {!bbox d=5}

Comment: What is the reason for having to pull out `pt` and `sfield` parameters, but leaving `d` parameter within the curly braces?

Comment: So called "Query Parsers" like bbox first look for a parameter in its local-params and then fall back to the top URL parameters.  They need to be at the top level so that geodist() will see them.